# Handling subscription downgrades with Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel Cashier (Stripe) as part of my Laravel 8 project. My project allows a user to add **domains** and **monitors** to their account, by default users can add/delete as many domains and monitors as they wish up-to 50 whilst on a free plan.

They can then upgrade their account to a PRO subscription with different subscriptions that contain different amounts of additional domains/monitors, e.g: 75, 100, 200.

So a scenario might be...

A user currently has 50 domains on their account, they then upgrade to the second PRO plan and add another 30 domains, so they now have 80 domains out of a possible 100.

If a user then downgrades their account back to the maximum of 50, how do I handle this in Laravel Cashier? How do I now effectively disable the ones added during that particular subscription?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store products and plans in the database. A product defines something a customer can subscribe to, and then a plan (price) determines the amount and interval (monthly, 6-monthly, yearly, etc). Then you just switch between them by storing the product and the plan that the user paid for in user's table.

Comment: Ok, I have a `plans` table with the following columns: title, slug, stripe_price, my `User` model then gets the plan but I can equally use `$user->subscribedToPrice($user->plan->stripe_id, 'default')` which I am. The Product as you say (in my example) is a **domain**, effectively what the user wants to get the expiry date of, but these don't have any connection to the plan, is your suggestion that I add a `plan` to my `domains` table and it gets marked with whatever plan the user added it on and then create a `where` query to retrieve these? @keneferinho95

Comment: When creating products in stripe you are defining price and billing cycle. You must store the same information in your database so you can retrieve information about your plans(products) synced with Stripe. (You are storing every Stripe plan separately because there is different price ID for every plan(product) created, no matter if it is the same plan(product) with different billing cycle or not). After that you just switch subscriptions between what you have in your database (what is currently available).

Comment: And now the big question - how do I add/restore domains if the plan that the user is switching to is with lower/bigger number of domains? You must store the user's available domains left somewhere with descending order (from high to low), which means if user's plan has 50 domains and he use 1 of them the current value of the available domains left will be 49. By storing user's current available domains this way you can easily swap between subscriptions because if user is swapping to 80 domains plan he will still have 49 left till the next billing date where he will be reset with 80 domains.

Comment: And if downgrading to 30 you can simply modify the value of user's available domains to 30.

Comment: Brilliant, that clarifies most things, I completely understand that somehow I need to keep track of the number of domains, however if a user adds a bunch of domains whilst subscribed to a plan, what happens when they downgrade? Sure, they won't be able to add any others but how do I know which ones were added during the subscription to know which ones to disable?

Comment: What is the point of allowing users to add domains while they can just subscribe to a plan? If a user can add domains while subscribed to a plan there is no point of these subscriptions.

Comment: You can either add a log as everyone would do. When you add a log you can easily track users as well as every user can also track himself. Just create a table in your database with 3-4 columns which will contain `user_id(relationship with users table)`, `what action did the user performed`, `when did he performed that action (date of spending a.k.a created_at)` and then create helper function so you can easily add logs in your database within your code. For example: `addLog( Auth::user()->id , 'Bought 15 domains' , Carbon::now() );`

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding. Let's assume there is a free plan that can have 50 domains, the user can always have 50. Then, there are three paid plans, one with 75 domains, 100 and 200 domains respectively, the user then upgrades to the 75 plan and adds 10 domains, so they have 60, when they then downgrade to free or cancel I need to know to only grab those 10 records and then disable them

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand you. I guess you will store somewhere the date of the downgrading/upgrading. If so you can easily catch which domains were added through the period of downgrading/upgrading to the current time. You can then use `whereBetween()` function in Laravel to catch records only between 2 dates and simply delete the records or do whatever you need to.